# What is fixed in a equation in a polynomial vector space

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

From what I've learned, an equation $p(t)$ in $P_n$ is defined
$$p(t) = a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\cdots+a_nt^n \tag 1$$
Given the basis $\beta=\{1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^n\}$, $p(t)$ can be written in the form
$$p(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &t &t^2&\cdots&t^n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
\vdots \\
a_n
\end{bmatrix} \tag 2$$

In (1) t is the variable of the equation and $a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n$ is fixed whose value is unchange. However, in (2) ${1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^n}$ is fixed because it form the basis of $P_n$ and $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is the variables of the equation.

Those definition contradict each other in my way to understand the nature of a polynomial equation.
For example: $p(t)=12t^2$ then t is the variable of the equation but if I write
$$p(t)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &t &t^2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
12 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then $t$ is unchanged but $a$ is

Answer (score 1):

In abstract algebra, one distinguishes between polynomials and polynomial functions. A polynomial $f$ in one indeterminate $X$ over a ring $R$ is defined as a formal expression of the form

$f = a_nX^n + \dots + a_1X^1 + a_0X^0 \tag{1}$

where $n$ is a natural number, the coefficients $a_0, \dots, a_n$ are elements of $R$, and $X$ is a formal symbol, whose powers $X^i$ are just placeholders for the corresponding coefficients $a_i$, so that the given formal expression is just a way to encode the sequence $(a_0, a_1, . . .)$. If you restrict the coefficients to a field $F$, then it gets the structure of a vector space.

Comment: Can you exlain it further.

Comment: When you are asked to solve a polynomial function, just consider it as a function in variable $x$. As said in my answer, when you consider a polynomial as vector, $X$ is just a formal symbol.